# Why does the unordered_map perform about 100 times slower than a 2d vector for look-ups?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, unordered-map, knapsack-problem

- I tried implementing the knapsack algorithm for large data sets.
- The 2d vector solution works perfectly for medium data sets around 100 items.
- Since the 2d vector won't be feasible for large datasets involving around 1000 items, I decided to use a hashtable and cache the values as required.
- I have used hash_value() from boost to hash std::pair into the unordered_map.
- But I don't understand why this solution works incredibly slower than
  the 2d vector solution. Aren't hashtables meant for super fast look ups?
- Both the implementations fail to process the large data set in finite time.
- I've attached the code and both the "medium" and "large" data sets.
- The code has both unordered_map and 2d vector implementations with the latter commented out.
- It would be really helpful if someone could point out the reason for the slow performance and suggest some optimization so that it is able to process the large dataset.
- The input file is of the form.
  (eg):

6 4 //weight, no of items
3 4
2 3
4 2
4 3

The optimal solution is 8.

[Download Link for Large dataset (1000 items)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kLAKFKEzAcbnNMUFlyRUhRRjA/view?usp=sharing)

[Download Link for Medium dataset (100 items)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kLAKFKEzAccklsRVl0NkJ3S28/view?usp=sharing)

[Download Link for Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kLAKFKEzAcU3UzbnlmY3BmOWs/view?usp=sharing)

//code follows:

//Headers, Macros and Global variables:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<boost/functional/hash.hpp>
using namespace std;

typedef vector< vector<long long> > vii;
typedef vector< pair<int,int> > vp;
typedef pair<int,int> myPair;
typedef unordered_map< myPair, long long, boost::hash<myPair> > myMap;

vp elmnts;
//vii arr2d;
myMap arr;
```

//Knapsack function:

```
long long knapsack(int n, int w)
{
//arr2d.resize(n+1, vector<long long>(w+1));
int vi,wi;

for(int j=0; j<=w; ++j)
//  arr2d[0][j] = 0;
    arr.emplace(make_pair(0,j), 0);

for(int i=1; i<=n; ++i)
{
    vi = elmnts[i-1].first;
    wi = elmnts[i-1].second;

    for(int j=0; j<=w; ++j)
    //  arr2d[i][j] = (wi > j) ? arr2d[i-1][j] : max(arr2d[i-1][j], arr2d[i-1][j-wi] + vi);
        arr.emplace(make_pair(i,j), (wi > j) ? arr[make_pair(i-1,j)] : max(arr[make_pair(i-1,j)], arr[make_pair(i-1,j-wi)]+ vi));
}

//return arr2d[n][w];
return arr[make_pair(n,w)];
}
```

//Main fucntion

```
int main()
{
ifstream file("/home/tauseef/Desktop/DAA2/knapsack1.txt");
int n,w;
string line;
pair<int,int> elmnt;

getline(file, line);
stringstream ss(line);
ss >> w;
ss >> n;

while(getline(file, line))
{
    stringstream ss1(line);
    ss1 >> elmnt.first;
    ss1 >> elmnt.second;
    elmnts.push_back(elmnt);
}

cout<<"\nThe optimal solution is: "<<knapsack(n,w)<<endl;
file.close();
}
```

Comment: `O(1)` lookup doesn't mean it is faster than `O(n)` lookup! It only means that for values of `n` greater than some value `n0` on a certain, imaginary machine `O(1)` is faster than `O(n)`.

Comment: `O(1)` means a fixed time, which could be 1 hour. `O(n)` can mean n seconds.

Comment: well, can you point out any optimizations that could help this code process the large data set with 2000 items? @UlrichEckhardt

Comment: Never looked at it that way @BoPersson thanks :)
But can you help me figure out why this code wouldn't process the large data set?

Comment: Learn to use a profiler.

Comment: O(1) means that, amortized, the cost of a call is the same regardless of how large the data set is. For example, vector push_back is O(1): but wait, sometimes its quick and sometimes it requires a memory allocation and copy of the existing data set! How can it be O(1)!

That's because O(1) doesn't have anything to do with the actual number of instructions or cost, it just says that the cost has nothing to do with the size of the data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Didn't expect the difference to be so huge: On my machine the array version is 100 times faster than the hash_map version. But after thinking about it...

You should expect the map being slower - there is a lot of overhead: invoking make_pair, creating a pair-object, calculating hash, searching it in the map, constructing return value, copying objects back and forth opposed to just looking-up the value!

On the other hand you don't profit from your switch to the map **at all** because in the end, as it is coded right now, you have the same elements in your map as in the array. Your change would make sense if you would leave some elements out from your map, but you don't do it.

But the bigger problem in your code is that you use the pseudo-polinomial algorithm from wikipedia which needs `O(n*W)` memory. That means you would need 32GB memory for the bigger test cases, which could mean swapping memory with the hard disc, depending on how big your system is and getting really sloooow.

The solution is to take the version of the algorithm which needs `O(W)` memory:

```
long long knapsack(const vector<myPair> &objects, int W)
{
    vector<long long> bests(W+1, -1L);//-1 = this value is not reachable
    //the only possible configuration at start: an empty set, value is also 0
    bests[0]=0;


    for(const myPair &object:objects){//try out all objects
        int v = object.first;
        int w = object.second;
        //update all possible configurations:
        for(int cur=W;cur>=0;--cur){//backwards->object at most once in every configuration!
          int next=cur+w;
          if(bests[cur]!=-1 && next<=W)//consider only reachable configurations and discard too big weights
            bests[next]=std::max(bests[next], bests[cur]+v);
       }
    }

    return *max_element(bests.begin(), bests.end());
}
```

The most important part is that we go backwards through the possible configurations and thus can update the configurations in-place (the updated configurations are the ones already proceeded in the current sweep).

I guess this version should need less than 1 minute for the bigger case (which is pretty reasonable considering how big the input is). I don't guaranty that this is bug-free, but hope you can get the gist of it.

Comment: Thank you so much @ead :) This is just what i needed.
Sorry for the late response, was pondering on why the code produced incorrect results. 
Please approve the edit so that i can accept your answer :)